# How to remove array from values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
{"contact_uuid": ["67460e74-02e3-11e8-b443-00163e990bdb"], "choices": ["None"], "value": [""], "cardType": [""], "step": ["None"], "optionId": ["None"], "path": [""], "title": [""], "description": [""], "message": [""]}
```

But I'd like to remove the lists so it looks like this:

```
{'contact_uuid': '67460e74-02e3-11e8-b443-00163e990bdb', 'choices': "None", "value": "", 'cardType': "", 'step': 'None', 'optionId': 'None', 'path': '', 'title': "", 'description': "", 'message': ""}
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I think I might be able to iterate through and remove the list. Thanks

Comment: `dict['contact_uuid']=dict['contact_uuid'][0]` ?

Comment: Some of the values in your output dictionary are retained as lists. How do you decide which ones to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to produce the required output you will need a list (set) of keys that should not be modified. Something like this:

```
dict_ = {
    "contact_uuid": ["67460e74-02e3-11e8-b443-00163e990bdb"],
    "choices": ["None"],
    "value": [""],
    "cardType": [""],
    "step": ["None"],
    "optionId": ["None"],
    "path": [""],
    "title": [""],
    "description": [""],
    "message": [""]
}

for k, v in dict_.items():
    if isinstance(v, list) and k not in {'value', 'cardType', 'step', 'optionId', 'path'}:
        dict_[k] = v[0]

print(dict_)
```

**Output:**

```
{'contact_uuid': '67460e74-02e3-11e8-b443-00163e990bdb', 'choices': 'None', 'value': [''], 'cardType': [''], 'step': ['None'], 'optionId': ['None'], 'path': [''], 'title': '', 'description': '', 'message': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that parse_qsl had a keep_blank attribute. It still returns the values in a list though which isn't always great especially in my case.

```
json_url = (parse_qs(url, keep_blank_values=True))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's is Python one liner with dict comprehension:

```
dict_new = {k: v[0] for k, v in dict_original.items()}
```

If you need to filter out certain keys, as pointed out by @Lancelot du Lac:

```
filter_keys = {'value', 'cardType', 'step', 'optionId', 'path'}
dict_new = {k: v[0] if k not in filter_keys else v for k, v in dict_original.items()}
```

Comment: Rarely a good idea to override Python built-in functions like that

Comment: what built-in function override are you pointing towards? @LancelotduLac

Comment: you are overriding dict

Comment: Updated the naming convention. `dict` was just a placeholder for any variable name that the OP has.